# Debugging Spring-WS request from MessageDispatcher to Endpoint?

Tags: web-services, debugging, jaxb, spring-ws, jaxb2

Is there a way to debug step-by-step what happens on a web service request in Spring-WS from the time the request is sent to the `MessageDispatcher` until it reaches my `Endpoint` (including `EndpointMapping`s, `EndpointAdapter`s, etc.)? Specifically, I would like to see how the unmarshalling of my XML request to Java objects is being handled via JAXB, as I'm getting some errors with that. I'm currently using soapUI as the client and RAD 8 with WebSphere 7 as the IDE and server. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse I can set breakpoints in jar files if I attach the source to it. I never worked with 'RAD', but I assume you can set breakpoints in third party libraries as well.

With a bit of debugging you should be able to determine where the unmarshalling takes place.

Comment: RAD is Rational Application Developer. It's built on top of Eclipse with IBM's own stuff added onto it. See http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/application/